# OpenfileDialog - Window is not popping out

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, openfiledialog

I am working on form . I want small window to pop up when I click button and to will select XML file of my choice from various folder.

I guess, this OpenFileDialog will help me.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   /
    OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.Filter = " XML Files|*.xml";

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"D:\";



    if (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(filed.FileName.ToString());
    }
}
```

I tried using following code but when I click on the button there window doesn't pop up.
I am not geting what mistake I have made.

What is the problem with that?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) If this is a console app, how come there are buttons? 2) What is `filed` - did you mean `openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()`? 3) Has `button3_Click` been registered as an event-handler for the button's `Click` event?

Comment: sorry..i have changed the mistakes !!!! its proper now.it is FORM, filed has been replaced..yes it has ben registered as click event !

Comment: Yes it must be form :) I gave an answer below, you are missing ShowDialog();

Comment: lets see if it works for me. !!! i will try that

Comment: its not wrking yet......
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            openFileDialog1.Filter = " XML Files|*.xml";
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"D:\";
            path = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
            

            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            
  }

Comment: So you are giving us not enough information about you app. Because, I wrote this code on mu Visual Studio, and it worked.Showed me a dialog. private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();

            f.ShowDialog();
        }

Answer (score 4):

You cant just [open](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/91942/showdialog-on-openfiledialog-not-showing-the-dialog) the file dialog from a console app. You will have to workaround it with some setting to [single thread apartment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute%28vs.71%29.aspx) (STA).

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

**--EDIT--**

Following works on click event:

```
OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
f.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
f.InitialDirectory = "D:\\"; 
if(f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show(f.FileName);  
}
```

Comment: Sorry. its form buddy !! i m st8ll no geting it ....code ...............
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            openFileDialog1.Filter = " XML Files|*.xml";
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"D:\";
            path = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
            

            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            
  }

Answer (score 2):

You cant open file fialog in console app.

You say I have button, so this must be Win app, use

openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); is missing

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.Filter = " XML Files|*.xml";

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"D:\";

            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            // Get file name and use OpenFileDialog1.FileName or something like that

       }
```